# How to download file JSON with Gecko Fx 45 or WebClient?

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx, webclient

How to download file json with Gecko or WebClient in WindowsForm?

[image: Picture Here]

This is address :

```
data:attachment/json;charset=utf-8,%7B%22installed%22%3A%7B%22client_id%22%3A%22320603424726-n3bmijvumva2hpg6h4ggoecm8fn7mkde.apps.googleusercontent.com%22%2C%22project_id%22%3A%22astute-helper-155008%22%2C%22auth_uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Fauth%22%2C%22token_uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Ftoken%22%2C%22auth_provider_x509_cert_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Foauth2%2Fv1%2Fcerts%22%2C%22client_secret%22%3A%22QXGaNOWokfXUvaepxaaWuNe8%22%2C%22redirect_uris%22%3A%5B%22urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%22%5D%7D%7D
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get it. Please correct if there is a mistake. Do you want to download the json file on the page you went with Gecko? If so, you can parse it with [htmlagiltypack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) and then download the download link you obtained with webclient.